# Recording real-time data collection with interrupt on Arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupt, real-time-clock

I've been working on collecting flow rates using the Arduino interrupt and I want to time stamp the data using a real-time clock.

I have both sketches working individually using the Arduino examples, but when I combine them it only writes to the serial port once and I am not sure why.

Once I have the pulse count I will save to a SD card for data manipulation.

```cpp
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_DS1307 rtc;
int Pulses =2;            //Digital Pin 2 on Uno
volatile int pulsecount;  //Volatile integer to store pulse count in

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  rtc.begin();            //start rtc
    
  pinMode(Pulses, INPUT); //Make Pin2 Input
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pulses), CountPulses ,FALLING); //Use interrupt on "Pulses" Pin, count on the falling edge, store in CountPulses
}

//create a function that adds up the pulsecount
void CountPulses() {
  pulsecount++;
}

void loop() {
  DateTime time = rtc.now();  //Get the time from RTC
  Serial.print(String("DateTime::TIMESTAMP_TIME:\t") + time.timestamp(DateTime::TIMESTAMP_TIME)); //Print the time to serial monitor

  pulsecount = 0; // set initial count to zero
  interrupts();   // start interrupt
  delay(5000);    // count pulses for 5 seconds
  noInterrupts(); // stop interrupt

  Serial.print(",");  
  Serial.println(pulsecount); //Feed pulse count to serial

  Serial.flush(); //flush the serial port to avoid errors in counting
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `noInterrupts()` stops *all* interrupts, not just the one you set up yourself. Any Arduino library code that uses interrupts in the background could stop working when you do this.

You should enable and disable *only* the interrupt you set up yourself.

Try replacing `interrupts();` with `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pulses), CountPulses, FALLING);` and replacing `noInterrupts();` with `detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pulses));`

You can then also remove the `attachInterrupt()` from `setup()`, as it is no longer needed.

Comment: Works a treat now, thank you, now to save to save to an SD card on the shield, hopefully get this without asking a question.